# Why the font in my equation is different?

Tags: fonts, math-mode

My code is

```
\newcommand\rsx[1]{\left.{#1}\vphantom{\Big|}\right|}
\begin{eqnarray}
&&let \;\; L(\bf{X},\lambda,\mu)= f(\bf{X})+\sum_{i=1}^p \lambda_{i}h_{i}(\bf{X})+\sum_{j=1}^q\mu_{j}g_{j}(\bf{X}) \nonumber\\
&& \;\;\;\;\; \rsx{\frac{\partial L}{\partial \bf{X}}}_{\bf{X}=\bf{X^*}}=0 \nonumber\\
&& \;\;\;\;\; \lambda_{i}\neq0,\;\;\;\mu_{j}\geq0,\;\;\;\nonumber\\
&& \;\;\;\;\; \mu_{j}g_{j}(\bf{X^*})=0,\;\;\; h_{i}(\bf{X}^*)=0 \;\;\; g_{j}(\bf{X^*})\leq0
\label{equ: KKT conditions}
\end{eqnarray}
```

and below is the result, as can be seen in this figure, the font type is different in these equations, why (see the letter "g" in different lines)?

[image: See the letter "g" in different lines]

Comment: You should use `\mathbf` instead of `\bf` I think... try it and see if it helps! Welcome to TeX.SX! Also, you may want to consider avoiding `eqnarray`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197/32374

Comment: @darthbith Thanks for your answer, I have solved this problem by adding `\usepackage{bm}` and replacing `\bf` with `\bm`, becaues we can not use `\bf{x}` to keep other letters from boldface. And thanks for your reminder of avoiding eqnarray. I'm trying other commands.

Comment: Glad it helped! You can write that as an answer to your own question and then people will see that it is solved :-)

Comment: The problem with `\bf` is just that you used the incorrect syntax but `bm` uses a different type of bold altogether. `\bf` uses bold upright roman, which should be accessed by `\mathbf{x}` whereas `\bm{x}` gives bold math italic.

Answer (score 2):

The alignment points could get some nicer fine-tuning, but I just wanted to correct some issues in your code. This is how I would type your formula:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\pder}[2][]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}
\newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\MoveEqLeft[7]\text{let } L(\mathbf{X},\lambda,\mu)= f(\mathbf{X})+\sum_{i=1}^p \lambda_{i}h_{i}(\mathbf{X})+\sum_{j=1}^q\mu_{j}g_{j}(\mathbf{X})\\
    \pder[L]{\mathbf{X}}\biggr|_{\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{X}^*}&=0\\
    \lambda_{i}&\neq 0,\quad\mu_{j}\geq 0,\\
    \mu_{j}g_{j}(\mathbf{X}^*)&=0,\quad h_{i}(\mathbf{X}^*)=0,\quad g_{j}(\mathbf{X}^*)\leq 0 \numberthis\label{equ:KKTconditions}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

or:

```
\begin{align*}
\MoveEqLeft[2]\text{let } L(\mathbf{X},\lambda,\mu)= f(\mathbf{X})+\sum_{i=1}^p \lambda_{i}h_{i}(\mathbf{X})+\sum_{j=1}^q\mu_{j}g_{j}(\mathbf{X})\\
    &\pder[L]{\mathbf{X}}\biggr|_{\mathrlap{\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{X}^*}}=0\\
    &\lambda_{i}\neq 0,\quad\mu_{j}\geq 0,\\
    &\mu_{j}g_{j}(\mathbf{X}^*)=0,\quad h_{i}(\mathbf{X}^*)=0,\quad g_{j}(\mathbf{X}^*)\leq 0 \numberthis\label{equ:KKTconditions}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The command `\bf` is a Plain-TeX command. While it continues to work in LaTeX, it's considered deprecated for use in LaTeX.

The immediate cause of the problem you've encountered is an incorrect use of `\bf`: it is a switch and doesn't take an argument. Hence, you should write `{\bf ...}` instead of `\bf{...}`. As you've "discovered", the scope of `\bf{...} ...` is *not* the material inside the curly braces; it extends to the end of the current (math) group.

For a LaTeX document, one shouldn't use `\bf` anymore. Write `\textbf{...}` or `{\bfseries ...}` for text material. For math material, use  `\mathbf{...}` if you want upright bold letters and `\bm{...}` (which requires the `bm` package) if you want *italic* bold letters.

There are two additional issues with your code snippet:

- Don't use the `eqnarray` environment: it's badly deprecated. Use an environment such as `align` instead. See the posting [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5001) for a thorough examination of the reasons for not using `eqnarray`.
- You seem to be engaging in quite a bit of visual formatting. This makes the code both hard to read and less flexible than you would probably like it to be. The code below suggests some alternative measures, and uses `align` instead of `eqnarray`. It also shows the different effects generated by `\mathbf` and `\bm`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for 'align' environment
\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand\rsx[1]{#1\vphantom{\Big|}\bigg\rvert}

\begin{document}

First with \verb+\bm{...}+:
\begin{align}
\text{Let }&L(\bm{X},\lambda,\mu)= f(\bm{X})
  +\sum_{i=1}^p \lambda_{i}h_{i}(\bm{X})
  +\sum_{j=1}^q\mu_{j}g_{j}(\bm{X}) \nonumber\\
&\rsx{\frac{\partial L}{\partial\bm{X}}}
  _{\bm{X}=\bm{X^*}} =0 \nonumber\\
&\lambda_{i}\neq0,\quad \mu_{j}\geq0,\nonumber\\
&\mu_{j} g_{j}(\bm{X^*})=0,\quad 
  h_{i}(\bm{X}^*)=0,\quad 
  g_{j}(\bm{X^*})\leq0
\label{equ:KKT_conditions}
\end{align}

\bigskip
Second with \verb+\mathbf{...}+
\begin{align}
\text{Let }&L(\mathbf{X},\lambda,\mu)= f(\mathbf{X})
  +\sum_{i=1}^p \lambda_{i}h_{i}(\mathbf{X})
  +\sum_{j=1}^q\mu_{j}g_{j}(\mathbf{X}) \nonumber\\
&\rsx{\frac{\partial L}{\partial\mathbf{X}}}
  _{\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{X^*}} =0 \nonumber\\
&\lambda_{i}\neq0,\quad \mu_{j}\geq0,\nonumber\\
&\mu_{j} g_{j}(\mathbf{X^*})=0,\quad 
  h_{i}(\mathbf{X}^*)=0,\quad 
  g_{j}(\mathbf{X^*})\leq0
\label{equ:KKT_conditions_alt}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```